# Ordering by meta value not working

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have set `WP_Query` to order by a meta value but it isn't ordering correctly for some reason. `entry_key` is a year but is stored as text eg: 2022

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order_by' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'entry_year',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'mica',
            'field' => 'ID',
            'terms' => $term->term_id
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Did you try adding `'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC'` to your arguments?

You didn't specify **what** the current behaviour is. Why is it not ordering correctly? How is it ordering now and how do you want the ordering to be?

By the looks of your code, could you try the following:

Change

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
```

In to

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I did try `meta_value_num` but it didn't change anything. I assumed that this was because the year value is saved as text and not a number. It is currently ordering by publish date but I want it to order by custom field `entry_year ` ie: 2022, 2021, 2020, 2019...

Comment: Wouldn't it be logical to just save the years as integers instead of text (string)? Or is there a reason to use strings?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense but there are a lot of records now and I am not sure of a quick way to change them to a number. Is it possible in the query to parse the text as in int or number?

Comment: Did you see my edit about using 'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC' to your arguments. You could try that first.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I have added it but the order is still incorrect ie: showing 2015 and 2019 records before 2021 custom post type records.

Comment: I ended up trying out `pre_get_posts` which seems to work!